# Is this class immutable or not?

Tags: java

The below class doesn't have `final` keyword but its member variables are `private` and `final` and the class exposes no mutate/set methods. Is this class immutable or not?

```
public class Abc {

    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    public Abc(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Is this class immutable or not?*" - Yes, it is immutable. --- "*The below class doesn't have final keyword*" - `final` on a class means that it cannot be subclassed.

Comment: Yes, it is. Although it's not `final`, `private` members are not accessible from the descendant class.

Comment: Direct instances if your class are immutable; indirect instances of your class are not necessarily immutable.

Answer (score 12):

The class itself is immutable, yes - if you create an instance of just `Abc`, no aspect of that can be changed after the instance has been created.

However, that doesn't mean that any code receiving a parameter of type `Abc` can assume it's immutable with all the benefits that carries... because the class isn't `final`. It's entirely possible for an object of a type *compatible* with `Abc` to be mutable:

```java
public class Mutable extends Abc {
    private String value;

    public Mutable(int id, String name) {
        super(id, name);
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now imagine you've got code which deals with an `Abc`:

```java
public class AbcConsumer {

    private final Abc abc;

    public AbcConsumer(Abc abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    // No need to create a defensive copy or anything like that...
    // abc is immutable, right?
    public Abc getAbc() {
        return abc;
    }
}
```

Here the consumer *assumes* it's fine to treat `Abc` as if it's an immutable class - but if someone creates an `AbcConsumer` by passing in a `Mutable` instance instead of "vanilla" `Abc` instance, it could cause problems.

That's why it's generally a good idea when you're creating an immutable type to make it `final` as well - that way any consumers know that if they receive a reference with that type, it's *definitely* immutable.

To put it another way: yes, the `Abc` class is immutable... but you can't assume that a reference with a compile-time type of `Abc` refers to an immutable object.

Comment: *if someone creates an `AbcConsumer` by passing in a `Mutable` instance instead of "vanilla" Abc instance* - I can't agree with this justification/reasoning; yes, you are absolutely right when considering hierarchy(ies) of the sub-types; however, the question is whether a class `Abc`, itself, is final or not. Yes, I see that your first words confirm just that.. but you still make an argument against it. If the consumer "deals" with what it returns, wrongly, does it deteriorate class's immutability? best is to just make immutable classes `final` - here I agree; however, this is also final. :)

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: I believe that answering the question *without* bringing up why immutability strategies favour `final` classes is likely to lead readers into a false sense of security. It's *really, really* important to understand in my view, hence the answer. Basically just because `Abc` is immutable doesn't mean that it's safe to treat a parameter of type `Abc` as referring to an immutable object. Given the second half of your comment, I don't see what objecting to within the first half.

Comment: Yes, after few more minutes, I agree with you now, more, than before.. as it really has to do with the broader perspective of usage of the `final` keyword - i.e. when omitting it can play important role. This scenario is (in my opinion) a very good example of *why* and *when* it matters to have your immutable classes `final`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash: Code that created the `AbcConsumer` may well retain a reference to it, and mutate it afterwards which the code consuming it might not have expected. Code that consumes it (calling `getAbc()`) can cast to `Mutable` and mutate it afterwards, which the code creating the consumer may not have expected. Basically it takes away a lot of the certainty that you'd normally want from immutability.

Answer (score 7):

As presented, yes, the class is immutable.

The "final" keyword on a class declaration prevents it from being extended - it's not related to immutability (unless your variables are declared public or protected).

Edit; "not related" is a poor choice of words, please see [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66519274/13463952) below

Comment: "*... (unless your variables are declared public or protected)*" - or `default` (aka. have no modifier).

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "not related" to immutability... will add an answer to explain why.

Comment: @Turing85 You're right. I based it on [Oracle docs on access control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), but apparently default variables are accessible from subclasses within the same package, otherwise inaccessible.

Comment: Not only subclasses of the package, but all classes in the package.

Answer (score 6):

**No**, it is most likely not.

A problem is terminology. What do you mean by *class*? If you mean **this code**, sure, it's immutable. But 'this code' is not something that is particularly relevant to the concept of immutability. That usually makes a lot more sense if we consider it: **this type**.

As in, is **the type** `Abc` immutable?

As in, given:

```
public void foo(Abc abc) { ... }
```

is it safe to assume that the received `abc` couldn't possibly change?

And then the answer is **no**. That is not safe to assume: The type `Abc` is **mutable**.

The reason is that someone could make this:

```
class SneakyAbc extends Abc {
    private int id;

    public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
       return id;
    }
}
```

This is why immutable classes are virtually always made `final`, to fully guarantee it.

Depending on how fancy you want to paint with the brush of 'what does this term mean', if **all** methods of Abc are `final`, you can consider it immutable as well if you really want to: Whilst the class does not need to be immutable (a subclass can add a new non-final field and create getters and setters for this), all the stuff you can 'witness' from the Abc type, assuming you don't use reflection, do appear immutable.

Exactly what definition of immutable you go with would be required knowledge to delve any further.

Note that something like `java.io.File` has only final fields and is final, and yet, it has easily observable state that can be modified: just.. delete the file, and voila you can see it. You can pull similar stunts with an `IdentityHashMap` to create a faux but nevertheless very observable 'field'.

Thus, 'immutable' as a concept: Useful. As a boolean flag to bestow upon a certain type or some java source file: Not useful.

Answer (score 2):

## Records

Other Answers directly addressed your questions about immutability, class being marked `final`, and subclasses being mutable. I’ll add an alternative option to more briefly accomplish your goal of immutability: *Records*.

[Java 16](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_16) brings the new [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature. If the main purpose of your class is to immutably and transparently carry data, define your class as a record. The compiler implicitly creates default constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

A record is implicitly `final`, so no risk of a subclass becoming mutable.

Declare the properties in parentheses. By default, you need not put anything in the curly braces body of a `record`.

```
record Abc ( int id , String name ) {}
```

Instantiate like any other class.

```
Abc x = new Abc ( 42 , "Snuffleupagus" ) ;
```

The implicit getter methods are simply the property names. The JavaBeans-style `get…`/`is…` method naming is *not* used. (You could add such methods if required.)

```
System.out.println( x.name() ) ;
```

> Snuffleupagus

Answer (score 1):

It is mutable if its internal states can be changed after the class is created.

In your example, although there is no class final, the inside situations cannot be changed again because of final keyword. In this way, the class becomes immutable again